# Values from two columns appear as a single column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One dataframe looks like this:

```
Thing       Number1      Number2     
   43           STK         
   64           BOX          
   32           STK          BOX
   46           THG          
   34           BOX          THG
...
```

And another one like this:

```
Thing        Package       Value1      Value2
   43            STK            1           1
   64            BOX            2           1
   64            STK            1           1
   32            STK            1           1
   32            BOX            2           3
   42            THG            1           1
   34            BOX            1           1
   34            THG            1           3
   34            STK            2           1
...
```

I want to eliminate the rows in the second dataframe that do not appear in the first (like  for `64` I only have `BOX`). I merged the two and eliminated the rows where the value in `Package` could not be found in either of Number1 or Number2, but is there any more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is efficient.

```
df = (df2.merge(df1, on='Thing')
        .query("Package == Number1 | Package == Number2")
        .drop(['Number1','Number2'], axis=1))
print (df)
   Thing Package  Value1  Value2
0     43     STK       1       1
1     64     BOX       2       1
3     32     STK       1       1
4     32     BOX       2       3
5     34     BOX       1       1
6     34     THG       1       3
```

Added alternative for multiple `Number` columns in `df1`.

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = df2.merge(df1.melt('Thing', value_name='Package')[['Thing','Package']])
print (df)
   Thing Package  Value1  Value2
0     43     STK       1       1
1     64     BOX       2       1
2     32     STK       1       1
3     32     BOX       2       3
4     34     BOX       1       1
5     34     THG       1       3
```